# Convert text to be written with symbols (lines, underlines for copyright in code files)

Tags: open-source, web-apps, plain-text

I found some time ago an online software which helps converting text in text written with symbols but I can't find it again. I need it for writting my company name in code files.

Example: "MM PP" should be something like

```
|\/| |\/|   |) |)
|  | |  |   |  |
```

Comment: It has to be open source, correct?

Comment: It has to be free. I think no one will pay for writting his name with keyboard's symbols. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this online application: bigtext.org. There is an input where you can write text and then choose a style for the text.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE (November 2019):** bigtext.org is offline. You can use this: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [TOIlet](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/toilet):

> The TOIlet project attempts to create a free replacement for
>   the ​FIGlet utility. TOIlet stands for “The Other Implementation’s
>   letters”, coined after FIGlet’s “Frank, Ian and Glen’s letters”.
>
> TOIlet is in its very early development phase. It uses the powerful
>   libcaca library to achieve various text-based effects. TOIlet
>   implements or plans to implement the following features:
>
> - The ability to load FIGlet fonts
> - Support for Unicode input and output
> - Support for colour fonts
> - Support for colour output
> - Support for various output formats: HTML, IRC, ANSI...
>
> TOIlet also aims for full FIGlet compatibility. It is currently able
>   to load FIGlet fonts and perform horizontal smushing.

Comment: @MMPP It's a command-line tool, I didn't saw it must be a web-app…